# window.onload javascript being block by body.onload (Radio Button Replacement) 

Tags: javascript, radio-button, onload, blocking, onload-event

I'm using the following script for a window.onload custom radio button replacement (http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/custom-form-elements.js) and I need to use a body.onload event to load a cookie:

```
<body onLoad="getCookie('cookie1')">
```

Obviously the problem I'm having is the body.onload is blocking the window.onload from running so the radio button replacements aren't showing up. I've seen a lot of "answers" on how to fix body.onload and window.onload interaction, but nothing has worked.

It doesn't matter which of the two scripts load first, I just need both to load correctly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call Custom.init from your body onload event handler, and then remove the last line from the custom-form-elements.js file.

Comment: I did this `code`<body onLoad="getCookie('cookie1'); Custom.init;">  but it isn't working...and I made sure to remove the last line from custom-form-elements.js file...

Comment: change that to <body onLoad="getCookie('cookie1'); Custom.init();"> notice the parentheses

Comment: done and done!!! I new I was missing something small... Thanks so much!!!! I think it is time for a coding break. :)